# Como declarar parâmetro opcional na rota do endpoint (.net)

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho o seguinte endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("/subcategories/products/{productId?}")]
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Buscar todas categorias com subcategorias e produtos",
                  OperationId = "Get")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategoriesWithProducts(int? productId = null)
{
    var response = await _categoriyQueries.GetCategoryWithProducts();
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Mesmo passando na rota com o "?" e também nos parâmetros ali `"int?"`, no Swagger ele aparece como Required. Como faço para considerá-lo opcional?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se o parâmetro é opcional então irá chamar outra rota, por exemplo, a rota que não possui parâmetros, que é a rota que lista todos...., que no caso seria a rota `/subcategorias/products/`.

Comment: Não tem como o parâmetro ser opcional e fazer parte da rota. Precisa ser um parâmetro por queryString daí

Answer (score -2):

Quando você declara uma variável na rota obrigatoriamente você precisa passar algum valor (nesse caso int) para chegar a essa rota.
Sugiro que você crie outra rota:
Ex: [HttpGet("/subcategories/products")]
Com isso você retorna em uma lista de produtos na rota sem query e a outra seria sua rota que receberá uma query, tornando assim opcional.